# How do I retrieve a default attribute and use it as part of execute resource?

Tags: chef-infra

I'd like to take the value of a default attribute,

```
[node][forwarder][username]
```

and pass it as an argument to an execute resource.  For example

```
execute 'set-up-boot-start' do
  command "/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk enable boot-start -user <username attribute>  --accept-license"
  user "root"
end
```

The Chef documentation doesn't make it very clear how to retrieve the values you set in attributes/default.rb.  I've tried

```
execute 'set-up-boot-start' do
  command "/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk enable boot-start -user [node][forwarder][username]  --accept-license"
  user "root"
end
```

But I get an error saying there's no such user in my Docker instance (in this case the user is 'nobody' which I thought all Linux systems had as a default).

Or if I use this notation (which I assumed called a 'get' method)

```
execute 'set-up-boot-start' do
  command "/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk enable boot-start -user "#{username}"   --accept-license"
  user "root"
end
```

Then I get an error about

> NoMethodError
>        -------------
>        undefined method `username' for Chef::Resource::Execute

I'm obviously a newbie at Chef and I've been pouring over their documentation but to no avail.

Edit:

I tried Raquel Guimarães suggestion which works with a directory resource I'm using just above the problematic lines but unfortunately it fails when I try using it in the execute resource:

```
        38:  execute 'set-up-boot-start' do
        39>>   command "/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk enable boot-start -user #{node['node']['dspe_splunk_forwarder']['username']}  --accept-license"
        40:    user "root"
        41:  end
```

The error message I get now is

> ```
>    NoMethodError
>    -------------
>    undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `#{node['forwarder']['username']}` should do the trick.

```
execute 'set-up-boot-start' do
  command "/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk enable boot-start -user #{node['node']['forwarder']['username']} --accept-license"
  user "root"
end
```

Comment: To expand this a little more, in Ruby the way you insert dynamic expressions in to a string (called "string interpolation") is to use double quotes and the `#{}` syntax, so `"foo#{1+2}"` == `"foo3"`. Single quotes do not process `#{}` interpolation. The thing inside the braces is any arbitrary Ruby expression, in this case using the `node` object to access Chef node attributes.

Comment: Thanks, I realize Chef is Ruby based and I've no experience whatsoever with Ruby.  Perl and bash shell scripting, awk, sed, and a little Python is my background.  Ruby seems a bit obtuse in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Raquel is essentially correct, however the extra

```
['node']
```

was causing the "Nilmethod" error because the attribute nested with that extra specification was incorrect.

Once I removed it the command ran as expected.